# Scoped services in ASP.NET Core with SignalR Hubs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I have introduced SignalR into my ASP.NET Core 2 project, but I'm having some issues using a **scoped** service that I normally use in my controllers. I feel like the problem may be due to the difference in lifecycles between HTTP requests, websockets and hubs.

On each HTTP request, middleware reads the `Authorization` token and updates some properties (e.g. id, claims, etc.) on a scoped service (`IUser`) for the request. I use this service in all of my controllers with no issue. To get this to work with SignalR, I am sending an `access_token` query parameter and using some other [middleware](https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/asp-net-core-and-signalr-authentication-with-the-javascript-client-d46c15584daf) beforehand to add this query parameter as a header which works fine.

The problem arises when I am trying to access the `IUser` service in my SignalR hub. On construction of the hub, the `IUser` that gets injected has none of the properties set, despite the middleware for the `/hub` request just setting them.

If I set the service to be a singleton then it works, but `IUser` should never persist longer than a single request.

How should I go about setting an `IUser` for a specific SignalR connection?

```
// Startup.cs - User has several settable properties 
services.AddScoped<IUser, User>();
```

```
// User Middleware
public class UserMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public UserMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // retrieve service for this request
        var user = context.RequestServices.GetService<IUser>();

        // set some properties on the User from auth token
        // e.g. User.Id = 1;

        return _next(context);
    }
}
```

```
[Authorize(Roles = Claim.Names.Read)]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IUser _user;

    public MyHub(IUser user)
    {
        // user that gets injected has null properties
        _user = user;
    }

    public async Task Foo()
    {
        // do work with the _user credentials
    }
}
```

```
public class DownloadController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUser _user;

    public DownloadController(IUser user)
    {
        // user gets injected and has properties set
        _user = user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Being that the hub is designed to interact with all registered clients, not just one particular user, the idea of using some sort of globally scoped "user" doesn't make much sense. What is it that you're actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ChrisPratt right, but a new hub instance is created for every method invocation, right? I'm trying to make some calls in the server-side hub methods that require an authenticated user. I could make the hub methods take a user as a parameter, but I thought it would be nicer to use middleware.

Comment: The `this.Context.User` property exists in the `Hub` base class, so I didn't think it was that unreasonable to try something similar with my own `IUser` class.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `Context.GetHttpContext().RequestServices` in your Hub-method? That should be the `IServiceProvider` of the ongoing request.

Answer (score -1):

To use scope service in signalr hub, you could inject `ServiceProvider` and create a scope in it directly:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{      
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public ChatHub(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider= serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task Foo()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
           var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

           var user = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUser>();    

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I want to use the scoped `IUser` that the middleware generates. The code above with just create a new `IUser` with no properties set.